# Corrupted PSD file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, cs5

I was working for several hours on a multilayer Photoshop CS 5 file when my computer crashed.

When I try to open the file, I can see the preview image of it:

[image]

But then get this message:

[image]

I've tried the following to fix it:

- REMO PSD Repair tool: Failed
- Opening the PSD as XML to see if I can fix the corruption: Failed
- Opening the file in Adobe Photoshop CS 6: Failed

I'm wondering if you guys can help me recover hours of work... Can I somehow open just the flat file I have (just as an image)? Any ideas?

Comment: Did you have [auto-save](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/recovery_function) enabled by any chance?

Comment: Restart PS. Try open - open recent. A bizarre thing to try; copy the file, and try opening the copy.

Comment: I'm flagging this as tech support, or perhaps it should go to SuperUser.com (although it's too old to migrate). This question is not about design.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have InDesign? If so, see if you can place the corrupted PSD file and then export it as either a PDF or JPG, (I personally prefer PDF for quality).
If this works you will at least now have your flattened version of your PSD.
Then open that up in Photoshop and create a new layer and carry on.

Good luck.